# Objective-C Remove all selected rows from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know about this call that would remove selected row:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

My question is, how do I remove all selected rows? as I have multiple selected.

Thanks,

Comment: I think the only way is to loop through all rows and deselect them!

Comment: `indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns a `NSArray` of `NSIndexPath`. What about then looping and deselect the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about rows deselecting you may do it like this:

```
    NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    [selectedIndexPaths enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO];

    }];

    [tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: This did not work, the selected rows still remain the same.

Comment: @user97931 I've just checked this approach on a test project and everything works fine. You may share your code so we can see where the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(_:withRowAnimation:)** with selected indexPaths.

Also you have to delete your objects from your datasource.

Comment: the OP needs to deselect the rows not to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```